# Tool to trace local function calls in Linux

Tags: linux, debugging, trace

I am looking for a tool like [ltrace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace) or [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) that can trace locally defined functions in an executable.  ltrace only traces dynamic library calls and strace only traces system calls.  For example, given the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int triple ( int x )
{
  return 3 * x;
}

int main (void)
{
  printf("%d\n", triple(10));
  return 0;
}
```

Running the program with `ltrace` will show the call to `printf` since that is a standard library function (which is a dynamic library on my system) and `strace` will show all the system calls from the startup code, the system calls used to implement printf, and the shutdown code, but I want something that will show me that the function `triple` was called.  Assuming that the local functions have not been inlined by an optimizing compiler and that the binary has not been stripped (symbols removed), is there a tool that can do this?

**Edit**

A couple of clarifications:

- It is okay if the tool also provides trace information for non-local functions.
- I don't want to have to recompile the program(s) with support for specific tools, the symbol information in the executable should be enough.
- I would be really nice if I could use the tool to attach to existing processes like I can with ltrace/strace.

Comment: have you looked into tracing with gdb? it once said me it only works for remote targets. maybe you can make gdb work with the remote target and conect to localhost? not sure, just some random idea.

Comment: I don't want to interrupt the program flow, if it is possible for gdb to unobtrusively trace a program like ltrace can I would be willing to try it if someone tells me how.

Comment: With GDB specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549693/gdb-list-of-all-function-calls-made-in-an-application/31814519#31814519

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Assuming you only want to be notified for specific functions, you can do it like this:

compile with debug informations (as you already have symbol informations, you probably also have enough debugs in)

given

```
#include <iostream>

int fac(int n) {
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    return n * fac(n-1);
}

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        std::cout << fac(i) << std::endl;
}
```

Use gdb to trace:

```
[js@HOST2 cpp]$ g++ -g3 test.cpp
[js@HOST2 cpp]$ gdb ./a.out
(gdb) b fac
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804866a: file test.cpp, line 4.
(gdb) commands 1
Type commands for when breakpoint 1 is hit, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>silent
>bt 1
>c
>end
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/js/cpp/a.out
#0  fac (n=0) at test.cpp:4
1
#0  fac (n=1) at test.cpp:4
#0  fac (n=0) at test.cpp:4
1
#0  fac (n=2) at test.cpp:4
#0  fac (n=1) at test.cpp:4
#0  fac (n=0) at test.cpp:4
2
#0  fac (n=3) at test.cpp:4
#0  fac (n=2) at test.cpp:4
#0  fac (n=1) at test.cpp:4
#0  fac (n=0) at test.cpp:4
6

Program exited normally.
(gdb)
```

Here is what i do to collect all function's addresses:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
readelf -s ./a.out | gawk '
{ 
  if($4 == "FUNC" && $2 != 0) { 
    print "# code for " $NF; 
    print "b *0x" $2; 
    print "commands"; 
    print "silent"; 
    print "bt 1"; 
    print "c"; 
    print "end"; 
    print ""; 
  } 
}' > $tmp; 
gdb --command=$tmp ./a.out; 
rm -f $tmp
```

Note that instead of just printing the current frame(`bt 1`), you can do anything you like, printing the value of some global, executing some shell command or mailing something if it hits the `fatal_bomb_exploded` function :) Sadly, gcc outputs some "Current Language changed" messages in between. But that's easily grepped out. No big deal.

Comment: I want to be able to trace all local functions and don't want to interrupt the program by setting breakpoints explicitly.

Comment: you could use objdump to get the functions and their addresses, and then use --command param to point gdb to a generated file which sets the breakpoint automatically.

Comment: @litb, yeah, that is what I am trying to do now, this might work, thanks for the insight.

Comment: @litb, this seems to work, I can attach to a running process, don't need extra debugging symbols, and the program interruption reasonable.  I just need to figure out how to start gdb from a script and send the output to a file, I need to start spending more time with GDB :)

Comment: the next gdb version will have python support: http://tromey.com/blog/?p=412 we'll have fun then :p

Comment: @litb, I needed this functionality, so I wrote a Python script that does what you suggest, generating output for OpenGrok and GraphViz dot. If anyone's interested, you can grab it at https://github.com/EmmetCaulfield/ftrace. It does what I need, but I doubt if it's very stable. YMMV.

Comment: I had to add a new line at end of $tmp with just a 'c' in it, and run the gdb like so to completely automate the trace of a running process:

`echo c >> $tmp`

followed by

`gdb -batch --command=$tmp -p 15414 < /dev/null &> /tmp/gdb.log &`

Comment: Now we have `rbreak` so the answer can be updated?

Answer (score 23):

**System Tap** can be used on a modern Linux box (Fedora 10, RHEL 5, etc.).

First download the [para-callgraph.stp](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/general/para-callgraph.stp) script.

Then run:

```
$ sudo stap para-callgraph.stp 'process("/bin/ls").function("*")' -c /bin/ls
0    ls(12631):->main argc=0x1 argv=0x7fff1ec3b038
276  ls(12631): ->human_options spec=0x0 opts=0x61a28c block_size=0x61a290
365  ls(12631): <-human_options return=0x0
496  ls(12631): ->clone_quoting_options o=0x0
657  ls(12631):  ->xmemdup p=0x61a600 s=0x28
815  ls(12631):   ->xmalloc n=0x28
908  ls(12631):   <-xmalloc return=0x1efe540
950  ls(12631):  <-xmemdup return=0x1efe540
990  ls(12631): <-clone_quoting_options return=0x1efe540
1030 ls(12631): ->get_quoting_style o=0x1efe540
```

See also: [Observe, systemtap and oprofile updates](http://gnu.wildebeest.org/diary/2008/11/27/observe-systemtap-and-oprofile-updates/)

Comment: Just wanted to note, this may depend on kernel compile options; e.g. I got for the same command: "`semantic error: process probes not available without kernel CONFIG_UTRACE while resolving probe point process("/bin/ls").function("*").call`"

Comment: This is not working for me with `semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'process' at a.stp:23:7` on Ubuntu 14.04. What is the working principle for system tap?

Comment: No need to specify the full path as argument to `process()`, `sudo stap para-callgraph.stp 'process.function("*")' -c /bin/ls` works just as well. To cut down on noise from library functions for which no debug symbols are available, you can use: `'process.function("*@*")'`.

Answer (score 12):

### Using [Uprobes](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2015-06-28/linux-ftrace-uprobe.html) (since Linux 3.5)

Assuming you wanted to trace all functions in `~/Desktop/datalog-2.2/datalog` when calling it with the parameters `-l ~/Desktop/datalog-2.2/add.lua ~/Desktop/datalog-2.2/test.dl`

1. `` cd /usr/src/linux-`uname -r`/tools/perf ``
2. `` for i in `./perf probe -F -x ~/Desktop/datalog-2.2/datalog`; do sudo ./perf probe -x ~/Desktop/datalog-2.2/datalog $i; done ``
3. `sudo ./perf record -agR $(for j in $(sudo ./perf probe -l | cut -d' ' -f3); do echo "-e $j"; done) ~/Desktop/datalog-2.2/datalog -l ~/Desktop/datalog-2.2/add.lua ~/Desktop/datalog-2.2/test.dl`
4. `sudo ./perf report -G`

[image: list of functions in datalog binary]
[image: call tree when selecting dl_pushlstring, showing how main called loadfile called dl_load called program called rule which called literal which in turn called other functions that ended up calling dl_pushlstring, scan (parent: program, that is, the third scan from the top) which called dl_pushstring and so on]

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you can re-compile (no source change required) the code you want to trace with the gcc option `-finstrument-functions`, you can use [etrace](https://github.com/creechley/etrace) to get the function call graph.

Here is what the output looks like:

```
\-- main
|   \-- Crumble_make_apple_crumble
|   |   \-- Crumble_buy_stuff
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   \-- Crumble_prepare_apples
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_skin_and_dice
|   |   \-- Crumble_mix
|   |   \-- Crumble_finalize
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_put
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_put
|   |   \-- Crumble_cook
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_put
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_bake
```

On Solaris, truss (strace equivalent) has the ability to filter the library to be traced. I'm was surprised when I discovered strace doesn't have such a capability.

Comment: Don't you have to compile + link ptrace.c against your code to make this work? Not always a reasonable task when you have a big code base with a giant make file :)

Comment: @philant I forgot about that option. Really nice.

Answer (score 6):

**KcacheGrind**

https://kcachegrind.github.io/html/Home.html

Test program:

```
int f2(int i) { return i + 2; }
int f1(int i) { return f2(2) + i + 1; }
int f0(int i) { return f1(1) + f2(2); }
int pointed(int i) { return i; }
int not_called(int i) { return 0; }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int (*f)(int);
    f0(1);
    f1(1);
    f = pointed;
    if (argc == 1)
        f(1);
    if (argc == 2)
        not_called(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
sudo apt-get install -y kcachegrind valgrind

# Compile the program as usual, no special flags.
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -o main -std=c99 main.c

# Generate a callgrind.out.<PID> file.
valgrind --tool=callgrind ./main

# Open a GUI tool to visualize callgrind data.
kcachegrind callgrind.out.1234
```

You are now left inside an awesome GUI program that contains a lot of interesting performance data.

On the bottom right, select the "Call graph" tab. This shows an interactive call graph that correlates to performance metrics in other windows as you click the functions.

To export the graph, right click it and select "Export Graph". The exported PNG looks like this:

[image]

From that we can see that:

- the root node is `_start`, which is the actual ELF entry point, and contains glibc initialization boilerplate
- `f0`, `f1` and `f2` are called as expected from one another
- `pointed` is also shown, even though we called it with a function pointer. It might not have been called if we had passed a command line argument.
- `not_called` is not shown because it didn't get called in the run, because we didn't pass an extra command line argument.

The cool thing about `valgrind` is that it does not require any special compilation options.

Therefore, you could use it even if you don't have the source code, only the executable.

`valgrind` manages to do that by running your code through a lightweight "virtual machine".

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ sudo yum install frysk
$ ftrace -sym:'*' -- ./a.out
```

More: [ftrace.1](http://sourceware.org/frysk/manpages/ftrace.1.html)

Comment: It's not clear to me from the man page if this will do what I want but this project seems to be in beta and not well-supported by any platform except Fedora.  I use several distributions, none of which is Fedora, and it looks like trying to get this to work with any of them would be a challenge.

Answer (score 4):

Since this question pops up in search results very prominently, I'll add another approach that 15 years later works with less hassles than others listed here: `uftrace`

It requires compiling respective applications with `-pg -g` (or `-finstrument-functions` if you are only interested in function names but not arguments and return values).
You can then run the command interactively:

```
uftrace -a --no-libcall -f none <cmd>
```

Alternatively, it's also possible to record the tracing data first and then output it separately.

```
uftrace record -a --no-libcall -f none <cmd>
uftrace replay
```

The latter works cross-platform as well, e.g., you can run the record stage at system A, transfer the tracing data (directory `uftrace.data`) to system B, and then replay on machine B.

Used options:

- `-a` enables the output of all arguments and return values
- `--no-libcall` hides all standard libc functions
- `-f none` hides the duration and thread ID columns usually printed in the front

Another useful option is `-N`, e.g., `-N log_*` filters out all calls of functions whose name starts with `log_`. For more see the manpage of `uftrace-replay`.

If the output is missing return values, retry after disabling link-time optimizations. For some reason that made them hidden in my tests.

Running the example of the OP interactively with vanilla options (NB: the 30 is the output of the program to stdout):

```
# uftrace a.out 
30
# DURATION     TID     FUNCTION
   0.671 us [802533] | __monstartup();
   0.421 us [802533] | __cxa_atexit();
            [802533] | main() {
   0.060 us [802533] |   triple();
  11.882 us [802533] |   printf();
  12.263 us [802533] | } /* main */
```

C++ fac example just showing the gist:

```
# uftrace --no-libcall -a a.out
1
1
2
6
# DURATION     TID     FUNCTION
            [803250] | _GLOBAL__sub_I_fac() {
 107.551 us [803250] |   __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(1, 65535);
 108.473 us [803250] | } /* _GLOBAL__sub_I_fac */
            [803250] | main() {
   0.211 us [803250] |   fac(0) = 1;
            [803250] |   fac(1) {
   0.080 us [803250] |     fac(0) = 1;
   0.491 us [803250] |   } = 1; /* fac */
            [803250] |   fac(2) {
            [803250] |     fac(1) {
   0.070 us [803250] |       fac(0) = 1;
   0.340 us [803250] |     } = 1; /* fac */
   0.541 us [803250] |   } = 2; /* fac */
            [803250] |   fac(3) {
            [803250] |     fac(2) {
            [803250] |       fac(1) {
   2.464 us [803250] |         fac(0) = 1;
   2.725 us [803250] |       } = 1; /* fac */
   2.916 us [803250] |     } = 2; /* fac */
   3.086 us [803250] |   } = 6; /* fac */
  33.463 us [803250] | } = 0; /* main */
```

Answer (score 2):

If you externalize that function into an external library, you should also be able to see it getting called, ( with ltrace ).

The reason this works is because ltrace puts itself between your app and the library, and when all the code is internalized with the one file it can't intercept the call.

ie: ltrace xterm

spews stuff from X libraries, and X is hardly system.

Outside this, the only real way to do it is compile-time intercept via prof flags or debug symbols.

I just ran over this app, which looks interesting:

http://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/

But I dont think thats what you want.

Comment: I understand why ltrace is able to do what it does and that tracing local functions is more difficult but it would be nice if there was a tool that could attach to a process and automatically set breakpoints on all local functions automatically to trace them if this is what is required.

Answer (score 2):

If the functions aren't inlined, you might even have luck using `objdump -d <program>`.

For an example, let's take a loot at the beginning of GCC 4.3.2's `main` routine:

```
$ objdump `which gcc` -d | grep '\(call\|main\)' 

08053270 <main>:
8053270:    8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
--
8053299:    89 1c 24                mov    %ebx,(%esp)
805329c:    e8 8f 60 ff ff          call   8049330 <strlen@plt>
80532a1:    8d 04 03                lea    (%ebx,%eax,1),%eax
--
80532cf:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
80532d2:    e8 b9 c9 00 00          call   805fc90 <xmalloc_set_program_name>
80532d7:    8b 5d 9c                mov    0xffffff9c(%ebp),%ebx
--
80532e4:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
80532e7:    e8 b4 a7 00 00          call   805daa0 <expandargv>
80532ec:    8b 55 9c                mov    0xffffff9c(%ebp),%edx
--
8053302:    89 0c 24                mov    %ecx,(%esp)
8053305:    e8 d6 2a 00 00          call   8055de0 <prune_options>
805330a:    e8 71 ac 00 00          call   805df80 <unlock_std_streams>
805330f:    e8 4c 2f 00 00          call   8056260 <gcc_init_libintl>
8053314:    c7 44 24 04 01 00 00    movl   $0x1,0x4(%esp)
--
805331c:    c7 04 24 02 00 00 00    movl   $0x2,(%esp)
8053323:    e8 78 5e ff ff          call   80491a0 <signal@plt>
8053328:    83 e8 01                sub    $0x1,%eax
```

It takes a bit of effort to wade through all of the assembler, but you can see all possible calls from a given function.  It's not as easy to use as `gprof` or some of the other utilities mentioned, but it has several distinct advantages:

- You generally don't need to recompile an application to use it
- It shows all possible function calls, whereas something like `gprof` will only show the executed function calls.

Answer (score 2):

There is a shell script for automatizating tracing function calls with gdb. But it can't attach to running process.

blog.superadditive.com/2007/12/01/call-graphs-using-the-gnu-project-debugger/

Copy of the page - http://web.archive.org/web/20090317091725/http://blog.superadditive.com/2007/12/01/call-graphs-using-the-gnu-project-debugger/

Copy of the tool - callgraph.tar.gz

http://web.archive.org/web/20090317091725/http://superadditive.com/software/callgraph.tar.gz

It dumps all functions from program and generate a gdb command file with breakpoints on each function. At each breakpoint, "backtrace 2" and "continue" are executed.

This script is rather slow on big porject (~ thousands of functions), so i add a filter on function list (via egrep). It was very easy, and I use this script almost evry day.

Comment: The link you provided is broken now.

Comment: Alex Reinking, thanks, updated with archived version.

Comment: I wrote a similar tool in python using GDB python scripts + graphviz: https://github.com/tarun27sh/Python_gdb_networkx_graphs

Answer (score 1):

[Gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html) might be what you want

Comment: I am not looking to profile the code, just trace it.  I want to know each time a local function was called, what the arguments were, and what the return value is.  I also don't want to have to recompile the program with special support for a specific tool as gprof requires.

Answer (score 1):

See traces, a tracing framework for Linux C/C++ applications:
https://github.com/baruch/traces#readme

It requires recompiling your code with its instrumentor, but will provide a listing of all functions, their parameters and return values. There's an interactive to allow easy navigation of large data samples.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the [callgrind or cachegrind tools](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html) for [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) will give you the information you seek.

Comment: I've already looked into all the tools for valgrind, nothing does what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This is not the linux kernel based ftrace, but rather a tool I recently designed to accomplish local function tracing and control flow. Linux ELF  x86_64/x86_32 are supported publicly.

https://github.com/leviathansecurity/ftrace

Comment: Can you summarize the working principle here? Why not use for instance GDB's Python API instead?