# Make GDB print control flow of functions as they are called

Tags: c, debugging, dynamic, gdb, call-graph

How do I make gdb print functions of interest as they are called, indented according to how deep in the stack they are?

I want to be able to say something like (made up):

```
(gdb) trace Foo* Bar* printf
```

And have gdb print all functions which begin with Foo or Bar, as they are called. Kind of like gnu cflow, except using the debugging symbols and only printing functions which actually get called, not all possible call flows.

Tools which won't help include cachegrind, callgrind and oprofile, which order the results by which functions were called most often. I need the order of calling preserved.

The wildcarding (or equivalent) is essential, as there are a lot of Foo and Bar funcs. Although I would settle for recording absolutely every function. Or, perhaps telling gdb to record all functions in a particular library.

Some GDB wizard must have a script for this common job!

Comment: Not marking questions as "community wiki" may help you get more (and better) answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to trace local function calls in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311840/tool-to-trace-local-function-calls-in-linux)

Comment: https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/trace-and-profile-function-calls-with-gcc/

Answer (score 8):

In your case I would turn to the `define` command in gdb, which allows you to define a function, which can take up to 10 arguments.

You can pass in the names of functions to "trace" as arguments to the function you define, or record them all in the function itself. I'd do something like the following

```
define functiontrace
if $arg0
    break $arg0
    commands
        where
        continue
        end
    end

if $arg1
...
```

Arguments to a user-defined function in gdb are referenced as $arg0-$arg9.  Alternatively, you could just record every function you wanted to trace in the function, instead of using $arg0-9.

Note: this will not indent as to depth in the stack trace, but will print the stack trace every time the function is called. I find this approach more useful than strace etc... because it will log *any* function you want, system, library, local, or otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

There's `rbreak` cmd accepting regular expression for setting breakpoints. You can use:

```
(gdb) rbreak Foo.*
(gdb) rbreak Bar.*
(gdb) break printf
```

[See this](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#Set-Breaks) for details on breakpoints.

Then use `commands` to print every function as it's called. E.g. let α = the number of the last breakpoint *(you can check it with `i br` if you missed)*, then do:

```
(gdb) commands 1-α
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1-α, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>silent
>bt 1
>c
>end
(gdb)
```

Some elaboration: `silent` suppresses unnecessary informational messages, `bt 1` prints the last frame of backtrace *(i.e. it's the current function)*, `c` is a shortcut for `continue`, to continue execution, and `end` is just the delimiter of command list.

**NB**: if you trace library functions, you may want to wait for lib to get loaded. E.g. set a break to `main` or whatever function, run app until that point, and only then set breakpoints you wanted.

Comment: Thank you. Any thoughts on how we could also trace when a function exits (returns)? (Because with just a trace of which functions are called, the case of function A calling B and then C is indistinguishable from A calling B which called C.)

Answer (score 3):

Use the right tool for the job ;)

[How to print the next N executed lines automatically in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764382/automate-tracing-in-gdb/1123188#1123188)

Comment: A GDB script should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see litb's excellent anwser to a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311840/tool-to-trace-local-function-calls-in-linux#311912) ?

He uses readelf to get interesting symbols, gdb commands to get the trace, and awk to glue all that.

Basically what you have to change is to modify his gdb command script to remove the 1 depth from backtrace to see the stack and filter specific functions, and reformat the output with an awk/python/(...) script to present it as a tree. (I admit I'm too lazy to do it now...)

Comment: That looks like a very similar question, although more general in that I'm specifically asking about gdb (although I'd be happy with anything).

All the answers seem wrong though. The one you point to breaks on a specific func of interest and finds all it's callers. I want all func invocations.

Answer (score 0):

You may call `gdb` in batch mode (using `-x` option), break where you need and ask for backtrace (`bt`), then you filter the result using `grep` or `egrep`.

Indents are more difficult, however `bt` output is ordered so you have current function at the top of the trace and `main` at very bottom.

So you create file with commands:

```
br <function name where to break>
run
bt
kill
quit
```

then run `gdb <program> -x<command file>`

Filter strings that starts with `#<digit>` - you get stack trace.

Comment: But this requires to manually write every function name, there might be hundreds of them!