# Order of variable declaration in asm x86?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, stack, stack-overflow

Here the piece of code :

```
int main()
{

  char buffer[64];
  int check;
...
```

As you can see, `check` is declared **AFTER** `buffer`, so in the stack, we must have `check`  **ABOVE** `buffer` in the stack right?

However, when I disassembly (x86) it with gdb, this is what I got :

--> `check` at `0xbffff4f8`

--> `buffer` at `0xbffff4b8`

**My question : is there a specific order in the stack for local variable?**

Also, I have to tell you that I tried the same thing on another computer (x86 too, same gcc compilation options, but different gdb version and linux distrib), and the order is not the same...:S

Thanks !

PS: if you want more details, please see the screenshot : (left with computer 1 and right with computer 2) [image]

Comment: No, the compiler is not required to store them in any specific order. Variables may not even be in memory at all if they fit in registers or are optimized away entirely.

Comment: The variables can be in any order, and there may be any number of padding bytes before, after, or between the variables.

Comment: For clarity, the padding bytes serve to preserve alignment.

Comment: Ok I had doubts about it...thanks !

Comment: Post text, not images of text!

Comment: A declaration is not a definition. And the C standard does not even mandate using a stack for local variables. Why do you expect a specific code/memory layout? Does the program not run correctly?

Comment: Duke Nukem, your OS is ubuntu or debian? What is gcc version used? There is stack protection in gcc to reorder variables on stack, sometimes enabled.

Answer (score 3):

There is `-fstack-protect` in gcc to reorder stack variables, turned on by default in some Linux OS variant for almost 10 years, especially Ubuntu, Redhat, gentoo. Also default since [gcc 4.8.3](https://www.gentoo.org/support/news-items/2014-06-15-gcc48_ssp.html) ("4.9 and later enable -fstack-protector-strong.")

Ubuntu page about gcc defaults: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain/CompilerFlags

> Ubuntu-specific default compiler flags in the toolchain used to help provide additional security features to Ubuntu. ...
>   Default Flags `-fstack-protector` ... First enabled in Ubuntu 6.10.

Ubuntu page about stack protection https://wiki.ubuntu.com/GccSsp

> gcc 4.1 comes with SSP now, which is a nice technology to mitigate exploitability of many buffer overflows.  ... SSP provides a technology to stop exploitability of this class of vulnerabilities by (1) **reordering stack variables** ... RedHat and gentoo are using SSP by default for years

This reordering requires several `O(n^2)` walks on all local variables of function which will make compilation slower for long functions, for example "Why does compiling over 100,000 lines of std::vector::push_back take a long time?" - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034393/196561

> Deferred allocation is forced when `-fstack-protect` is enabled (sometimes it needs to reorder all stack variables). ..  [cfgexpand.c](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-4_6-branch/gcc/cfgexpand.c?revision=175029&view=markup)

```
969 /* A subroutine of expand_one_var.  VAR is a variable that will be
970    allocated to the local stack frame.  Return true if we wish to
971    add VAR to STACK_VARS so that it will be coalesced with other
972    variables.  Return false to allocate VAR immediately.
973 
974    This function is used to reduce the number of variables considered
975    for coalescing, which reduces the size of the quadratic problem.  */
976 
977 static bool
978 defer_stack_allocation (tree var, bool toplevel)
980   /* If stack protection is enabled, *all* stack variables must be deferred,
981      so that we can re-order the strings to the top of the frame.  */
```

So, gcc will reorder all stack variables, and strings will be at top of the frame. **Try `-fno-stack-protector` option to disable.**

As usual, gcc's author don't document how `-fstack-protect` works in public documentation https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html:

> `-fstack-protector`
>   Emit extra code to check for buffer overflows, such as stack smashing attacks. This is done by adding a guard variable to functions with vulnerable objects. This includes functions that call `alloca`, and functions with buffers larger than 8 bytes. The guards are initialized when a function is entered and then checked when the function exits. If a guard check fails, an error message is printed and the program exits.
>
> `-fstack-protector-all`
>   Like `-fstack-protector` except that all functions are protected.
>
> `-fstack-protector-strong`
>   Like `-fstack-protector` but includes additional functions to be protected — those that have local array definitions, or have references to local frame addresses.
>
> `-fstack-protector-explicit`
>   Like `-fstack-protector` but only protects those functions which have the `stack_protect` attribute.

And the only documentation of array-before-locals I see is the real, best documentation: source code

https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-4_6-branch/gcc/cfgexpand.c?revision=175029&view=markup#l1526 - `expand_used_vars()`

```
1533          if (has_protected_decls)
1534            {
1535              /* Phase 1 contains only character arrays.  */
1536              expand_stack_vars (stack_protect_decl_phase_1);
1537    
1538              /* Phase 2 contains other kinds of arrays.  */
1539              if (flag_stack_protect == 2)
1540                expand_stack_vars (stack_protect_decl_phase_2);
1541            }
1542    
1543          expand_stack_vars (NULL);
```

phase 1 and phase 2 vars are separated by `stack_protect_decl_phase()` https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-4_6-branch/gcc/cfgexpand.c?revision=175029&view=markup#l1235

```
1235    /* Return nonzero if DECL should be segregated into the "vulnerable" upper
1236       part of the local stack frame.  Remember if we ever return nonzero for
1237       any variable in this function.  The return value is the phase number in
1238       which the variable should be allocated.  */
1239    
1240    static int
1241    stack_protect_decl_phase (tree decl)
 ...
1243      unsigned int bits = stack_protect_classify_type (TREE_TYPE (decl));
 ...
1249      if (flag_stack_protect == 2)
1250        {
1251          if ((bits & (SPCT_HAS_SMALL_CHAR_ARRAY | SPCT_HAS_LARGE_CHAR_ARRAY))
1252              && !(bits & SPCT_HAS_AGGREGATE))
1253            ret = 1;
1254          else if (bits & SPCT_HAS_ARRAY)
1255            ret = 2;
1256        }
```

`stack_protect_classify_type` will return bits `HAS_ARRAY` with `HAS_*_CHAR_ARRAY` only for arrays of char (both [char, unsigned char and signed char](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-4_6-branch/gcc/cfgexpand.c?revision=175029&view=markup#l1195))

Comment: Thanks, I need a little time to understand everything in your answer.
I thought that `-fstack-protect` was only about adding canary into the stack in order to prevent stack based overflow.by checking if that canary was overwritten.
Can you confirm me that with `-fno-stack-protector` the order of the variable declared on the stack is conform at the declaration order in the source file?

Comment: `-fstack-protector` / `-fno-stack-protector` may (and will) change order of variables on the stack. You have the test, just compile it with `-fno-stack-protector` and check order. If my answer solves your problem, you may accept it by clicking "v"-shaped Accept button, or you may wait for other answers.

Comment: Ok. So if I understand well, order of variables on the stack may change even if we set `-fno-stack-protection` right? I can't check it at this moment but as soon as I can I will. Thanks

Comment: Order of variables on stack will change with `-fstack-protector`, and probably will not with `-fno-stack-protector`. The default is configured when gcc is build (or installed) into the system.