# log file that contains the execution flow of a C or C++ program

Tags: gdb, trace, execution, control-flow

I need to generate a log file that contains the execution flow of a C or C++ program.
This log file should contain each line of the program (with line number specified) in the order that is executed. 
What can be use for that? I tried with GDB but I couldn't do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GDB auto stepping - automatic printout of lines, while free running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947389/gdb-auto-stepping-automatic-printout-of-lines-while-free-running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDB can't do that automatically, but with simple script you should be able to step a program, until it ends and log everything.
This will execute very slowly, as CPU will handle a breakpoint every few instructions.
Also try looking into GDB's [process reply feature](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Process-Record-and-Replay.html).

There are other tools available for this purpose, as explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764382/automate-tracing-in-gdb/1123188#1123188).

Hardware tools exist that can capture program execution "trace" while program is running at full speed.

Comment: Thank you! I found my answer in the second link you send me. direct link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947389/gdb-auto-stepping-automatic-printout-of-lines-while-free-running/6964213#6964213)