# Break on namespace function in gdb (llvm)

Tags: namespaces, gdb, llvm

I'm trying to step through llvm's opt program (for an assignment) and the instructor suggested setting a breakpoint at `runOnFunction`. I see this in one of the files:

```
bool InstCombiner::runOnFunction(Function &F) { /* (Code removed for SO) */ }
```

but gdb does not seem to find the `runOnFunction` breakpoint. It occurred to me that the problem might be namespaces? I tried this but gdb never breaks, it just creates the fooOpt.s file:

```
(gdb) b runOnFunction
Function "runOnFunction" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (runOnFunction) pending.
(gdb) r -S -instcombine -debug -o ~/Desktop/fooOpt.s ~/Desktop/foo.s
```

I'm on a Mac so I don't have `objdump` but `otool` produces 5.6 million lines, wading through that for a starting point does not seem reasonable as runOnFunction appears more than once there.

Comment: `InstCombiner` was not namespace, it is class.. And it is class [`llvm::InstCombiner`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1InstCombiner.html) from `llvm` namespace. So, right command may sound like `break 'llvm::InstCombiner::runOnFunction(llvm::Function &F)'` or even just `break sourceFile.cpp:line`, where line is first statement in  runOnFunction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gdb has several builtin commands to find name of such functions. First is `info functions`, which can be used with optional `regexp` argument to grep all available functions, https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html

```
info functions regexp
```

> Print the names and data types of all defined functions whose names contain a match for regular expression regexp. Thus, ‘info fun step’ finds all functions whose names include step; ‘info fun ^step’ finds those whose names start with step. If a function name contains characters that conflict with the regular expression language (e.g. ‘operator*()’), they may be quoted with a backslash.

So, you can try `info functions runOnFunction` to get the name. Sometimes it can be useful to add quotes around name when doing `break` command.

The other way is to use `rbreak` command instead of `break` (`b`). `rbreak` will do regexp search in functions names and may define several breakpoints: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#Set-Breaks

```
rbreak regex
```

> Set breakpoints on all functions matching the regular expression regex. This command sets an unconditional breakpoint on all matches, printing a list of all breakpoints it set.  ...
>
> The syntax of the regular expression is the standard one used with tools like grep. Note that this is different from the syntax used by shells, so for instance foo* matches all functions that include an fo followed by zero or more os. There is an implicit .* leading and trailing the regular expression you supply, so to match only functions that begin with foo, use ^foo.

(or even `rbreak file:regex` to limit search to single source file)

PS: if you want, you can turn on or off C++ function name demangling with `set print demangle` `on` or `off` (https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Debugging-C-Plus-Plus.html#Debugging-C-Plus-Plus). With demangling turned off it will be easier to copy function name to `break` command.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I could use regex to find fuctions

Comment: Actually I did the same error when I patched the bash+gdb script `callgraph` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1980793/196561 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1980770/196561. I need get all function list from the executable, filter it with regex, and then define breakpoints on all filtered functions. I did this with `info functions` and external `grep`, and with `info functions regex` it will be much faster for big projects. Also, I should try to modify the `callgraph.tar.gz` to use `rbreak`, but I'm not sure if it possible to define `commands` for all breakpoints, generated by `rbreak`.

Comment: Yes, I did notice it was quite slow to do a regex search (the project is big) but `grep` works. Actually, since I know the file your suggestion of using that helps, thanks again

Comment: PS, setting breakpoints for C++ was always a hard part of gdb for me. There is manual with solution: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_gdb.html - ... "breakpoints in C++ programs" "*you need to specify methods and data members using the "classname::" prefix. In addition, you often need to use a leading ' before a name for gdb to find the symbol*", `(gdb) break 'BufMgr::pinPage(int, Page *&, int)'`