# GDB - show last n lines executed

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, control-flow

Sometimes in GDB I want to see the control flow that got the program to where it is now. Simply put, how do I make GDB print the last x lines executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is yet another use case for [Reverse Debugging](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial).

1. You should start process record and replay at some point:

   ```
   (gdb) record
   ```
2. When you want to see last executed lines you can go backwards like
   this:

   ```
   (gdb) reverse-step 3
   ```

   or

   ```
   (gdb) reverse-next 3
   ```
3. Use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1545732/72178 to actually
   print the next N executed lines.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. Works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

You simply cannot do that (easily) in `gdb`, because the execution trace of any program is *not* kept (and keeping it would be very expensive : it would slow down a lot the execution, and it would use a lot of resources - memory & disk space).

You can however use the `backtrace` or `bt` command of `gdb` to show the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), that is the current instruction pointer in the current function, the calling function, the calling function of the calling function, and so forth

BTW, if you really wanted it, you might script recent `gdb` using Python or Guile to give you such information. You certainly could keep the entire trace (by scripting around the `step` & `backtrace` functionalities).