# List of all function calls made in an application

Tags: gdb, callstack, gprof

How can we list all the functions being called in an application. I tried using GDB but its backtrace list only upto the main function call.

I need deeper list i.e list of all the functions being called by the main function and the function being called from these called functions and so on.

Is there a way to get this in gdb? Or could you give me suggestions on how to get this?

Comment: With any tool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311840/tool-to-trace-local-function-calls-in-linux?lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make GDB print control flow of functions as they are called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311948/make-gdb-print-control-flow-of-functions-as-they-are-called)

Comment: https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/trace-and-profile-function-calls-with-gcc/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> How can we list all the functions being called in an application

For any realistically sized application, this list will have thousands of entries, which will probably make it useless.

You can find out all functions *defined* (but not necessarily called) in an application with the `nm` command, e.g.

```
nm /path/to/a.out | egrep ' [TW] '
```

You can also use GDB to set a breakpoint on each function:

```
(gdb) set logging on     # collect trace in gdb.txt
(gdb) set confirm off    # you wouldn't want to confirm every one of them
(gdb) rbreak .           # set a breakpoint on each function
```

Once you continue, you'll hit a breakpoint for each function called. Use the `disable` and `continue` commands to move forward. I don't believe there is an easy way to automate that, unless you want to use Python scripting.

Already mentioned `gprof` is another good option.

Comment: Note: this will also break on code that runs before `_start`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379422/why-is-init-from-glibcs-csu-init-first-c-called-before-start-even-if-start-i

Comment: gdb has been sitting at 100% cpu since I entered the command `rbreak .`

Comment: without logging, `set height 0` will be helpful (no paging for output)

Comment: You can try `rbreak ^s[^@]*$` if you only want to set breakpoints on non system functions, i.e. exclude `malloc`, `strlen` & co.

Comment: @Johannes I think you need to remove that `s` after `^`  - all I got was non-system functions that starting in s...

Answer (score 14):

You want a call graph. The tool that you want to use is not gdb, it's `gprof`. You compile your program with `-pg` and then run it. When it runs a file `gmon.out` will be produced. You then process this file with `gprof` and enjoy the output.

Comment: I doubt gprof gives you the sequence of all function invocations.

Comment: It's not complete, but it's pretty good. Check out https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gprof-2.9.1/html_chapter/gprof_5.html and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/wrkshp50/805-4947/6j4m8jrn7/index.html

Comment: So, no, it's neither complete nor close. The link you gave shows it's one line per _stack of functions_, not per _call_ to a function or stack-of-functions. This is not what I need. If from main, I call a() then b() then a() then b() etc. - I want to get "main a b a b a b a b etc."

Comment: Do you mean that you want *every function call* that your program makes? Do you want just _your_ functions, or all library functions, all compiler support functions, etc. And what is your definition of a "function call" ?

Comment: Every call, in sequence.

Comment: Your best bet is instrumenting the compiler or modifying the intermediate code or the assembler. It is possible that this is what happens with gprof.

Answer (score 11):

**record function-call-history**

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Process-Record-and-Replay.html

This should be a great *hardware accelerated* possibility if you are one of the few people (2015) with a CPU that supports [Intel Processor Tracing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/09/18/processor-tracing) (Intel PT, `intel_pt` in `/proc/cpuinfo`).

GDB docs claim that it can produce output like:

```
(gdb) list 1, 10
1   void foo (void)
2   {
3   }
4
5   void bar (void)
6   {
7     ...
8     foo ();
9     ...
10  }
(gdb) record function-call-history /ilc
1  bar     inst 1,4     at foo.c:6,8
2    foo   inst 5,10    at foo.c:2,3
3  bar     inst 11,13   at foo.c:9,10
```

Before using it you need to run:

```
start
record btrace
```

which is where a non capable CPU fails with:

```
 Target does not support branch tracing.
```

CPU support is further discussed at: [How to run record instruction-history and function-call-history in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507169/how-to-run-record-instruction-history-and-function-call-history-in-gdb)

Related threads:

- [how to trace function call in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374005/how-to-trace-function-call-in-c)
- [Is there a compiler feature to inject custom function entry and exit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472769/is-there-a-compiler-feature-to-inject-custom-function-entry-and-exit-code)

For embedded, you also consider JTAG and supporting hardware like ARM's [DSTREAM](https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/debug-probes-and-adapters/dstream), but x86 support does not seem very good: [debugging x86 kernel using a hardware debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807046/debugging-x86-kernel-using-a-hardware-debugger)

Answer (score 3):

This question might need clarification to decide between what are currently 2 answers.  Depends on what you need:

1) You need to know how many times each function is being called in straight list/graph format of functions matched with # of calls.  This could lead to ambiguous/inconclusive results if your code is not procedural (i.e. functions calling other functions in a branch out structure without ambiguity of what is calling what).  This is basic gprof functionality which requires recompilation with -pg flag.

2) You need a list of functions in the order in which they were called, this depends on your program which is the best/feasible option:
a) IF your program runs and terminates without runtime errors you can use gprof for this purpose.
b) ELSE option above using dbg with logging and break points is the left over option that I learned upon reading this.

3) You need to know not only the order but, for example, the function arguments for each call as well.  My current work is simulations in physics of particle transport, so this would ABSOLUTELY be useful in tracking down where anomalous results are coming from... i.e. when the arguments getting passed around stop making sense.  I imagine one way to do this is would be a variation on what Employed Russian did except using the following:

> (gdb) info args

Logging the results of this command with every break point (set at every function call) gives the args of the current function.

Answer (score 1):

With [`gdb`](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb), if you can find the most child function, you can list its all ancestors like this:

```bash
gdb <your-binary>

(gdb) b theMostChildFunction ## put breakpoint on the desired function
(gdb) r ## run the program
(gdb) bt ## backtrace starting from the breakpoint
```

Otherwise, on linux, you can use [`perf`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/) tool to trace programs and their function calls. The advantage of this, it is tracing all processes including child processes and also it shows usage percentages of the functions in the program.

You can install `perf` like this:

```bash
sudo apt install linux-tools-generic
sudo apt install linux-cloud-tools-generic
```

Before using `perf` you may also need to remove some kernel restrictions temporarily:

```bash
sudo sh -c 'echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict'
sudo sh -c 'echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid' 
sudo sh -c 'echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope'
```

After this, you can run your program binary with `perf` like this:

```bash
perf record -g -s -a <your-binary-and-its-flags>
```

Then either you can look the output on terminal like this:

```bash
perf report
```

or on text file like this:

```bash
perf report -i perf.data > output.txt
vim output.txt
```

when you are recording the function calls with `perf` also you may want to filter kernel calls with `--all-user` flag:

```bash
perf record -g -s -a --all-user <your-binary-and-its-flags>
```

For further information you can look here: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial