# debugging x86 kernel using a hardware debugger

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, x86

I have a code running in Ring0 and it is crashing. I do not have any gdb server in my software. It is pure assembly diagnostic software. I am using Corei7

In embedded systems I used a hardware debugger (with Jtag), I can stop the core and check the exception registers...
I am not able to find the same process in x86 based boards.

Can someone point out how they do debugging of assembly code without using gdb.... Or if you use a JTAG/HW debugger please let me know as well

thanks

Comment: Also take a look at the crash utility.  I got the impression that any JTAG accessibility is limited on x86 for security reasons.  Another option is to use the Linux kernel debugger via a serial port.

Comment: Yes, if this is actually a linux kernel you can use kgdb.  Another option could be to run the code in a VM or even processor simulator, which has the potential to give you even more control than a typical JTAG debug extension would.  Of course the cheapest debug method to set up is to really think about the code and then put in logging for suspected causes.