# Why is _init from glibc's csu/init-first.c called before _start even if _start is the ELF entry point?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb, glibc

I first noticed it while playing with GDB's `rbreak .`, and then made a minimal example:

```
(gdb) file hello_world.out
Reading symbols from hello_world.out...done.
(gdb) b _init
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4003e0
(gdb) b _start
Breakpoint 2 at 0x400440
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/ciro/bak/git/cpp/cheat/gdb/hello_world.out

Breakpoint 1, _init (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd698, envp=0x7fffffffd6a8) at ../csu/init-first.c:52
52  ../csu/init-first.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000000000400440 in _start ()
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004003e0 in _init ()
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   <MULTIPLE>
    breakpoint already hit 2 times
1.1                         y     0x00000000004003e0 <_init>
1.2                         y     0x00007ffff7a36c20 in _init at ../csu/init-first.c:52
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000400440 <_start>
    breakpoint already hit 1 time
```

Note that there are 2 `_init`: one in `csu/init-first.c`, and the other seems to come from `sysdeps/x86_64/crti.S`. I'm talking about the `csu` one.

Isn't `_start` supposed to be the entry point set by the linker, and stored in the ELF header? What mechanism makes `_init` run first? What is its purpose?

Tested on GCC 4.8, glibc 2.19, GDB 7.7.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Not really. There is init section defined in ELF. Take a look at [THIS](http://l4u-00.jinr.ru/usoft/WWW/www_debian.org/Documentation/elf/node3.html) You could also try `readelf -d yourelf` to check INIT and FINI sections. Anyway if you compile with -nostdlib those part are avoided.

Answer (score 9):

Where the debugger halts first in your example isn't the real beginning of the process.

In the ELF header there is an entry for the program interpreter (dynamic linker). On Linux 64 bit its value is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. The kernel sets the initial instruction pointer to the entry point of this **program interpreter**. The symbol name of it is `_start` too, like the programs `_start`.

After the dynamic linker has done its work, calling also functions in the program, like `_init` in glibc, it calls the entry point of the program.

The breakpoint at `_start` doesn't work for the dynamic linker because it takes only the address of the program's `_start`.

You can find the entry point address with `readelf -h /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

You could also set a breakpoint at `_dl_start` and print a backtrace to see that this function is called from dynamic linker's `_start`.

If you download glibc's current source code you can find the entry point of the dynamic loader at `glibc-2.21/sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h` starting on line 121.

Comment: Thanks! glibc is so huge, it also contains the loader.