# How to set breakpoints on all symbols in a shared library

Tags: python, gdb

I want to inspect the `math` operations on `numpy`, which was written by `python` and `c`. I debugged it with `gdb` and found that the `math` library is `_multiarray_umath.cpython-36dm-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. There are so many overload `python` functions that I'm not sure where to set the breakpoints for `_multiarray_umath.cpython-36dm-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

Is there any method to break all the symbols on a shared library?

Comment: This is close to a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/9549822/50617

Comment: I had tried this way and it worked around this problem. But I wanted to seek more trick way to do this. Is there any more simpler method? Such as through gdb features?