# Using gdb stop the program when it is using any function from file X

Tags: gdb

and I would like to know if there is any way to stop a program when is using a function from a certain file. Ideally what I am looking for is something like:

```
GDB Stop when use a function from file foo.cpp
```

The reason to do this is because I am debugging a code that is not mine and I do not know exactly what functions are been called and what functions are not. Is there a function in GDB to do what I am looking for, or any other recommended way to do something similar?.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Step 1: construct a list of all functions defined in `foo.cpp`
The simplest way I can think of (assuming you have `binutils` and GNU `grep`):

```
nm a.out | grep ' T ' | addr2line  -fe a.out |
  grep -B1 'foo\.cpp' | grep -v 'foo\.cpp' > funclist
```

Step 2: construct a GDB script which will set a break point on each of the above functions:

```
sed 's/^/break /' funclist > stop-in-foo.gdb
```

[Obviously, steps 1 and 2 could be combined ;-]

Step 3: actually set the breakpoints:

```
gdb a.out
(gdb) source stop-in-foo.gdb
```

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311840/tool-to-trace-local-function-calls-in-linux#312058) answer, an even simpler (if you are on Fedora Linux) way to find out which foo.cpp functions are called:

```
ftrace -sym='foo.cpp#*' ./a.out
```

Too bad [ftrace](http://sourceware.org/frysk/manpages/ftrace.1.html) man page says this isn't implemented yet.

Comment: I was going to say to do this, but +1 for actually doing it.  =)

Comment: Does not seem to pick up static functions.

Answer (score 12):

**`rbreak regex`**

Set breakpoints on all functions matching the regular expression regex. This command sets an unconditional breakpoint on all matches, printing a list of all breakpoints it set. Once these breakpoints are set, they are treated just like the breakpoints set with the break command. You can delete them, disable them, or make them conditional the same way as any other breakpoint.

The syntax of the regular expression is the standard one used with tools like `grep'. Note that this is different from the syntax used by shells, so for instance foo* matches all functions that include an fo followed by zero or more os. There is an implicit .* leading and trailing the regular expression you supply, so to match only functions that begin with foo, use ^foo.

When debugging C++ programs, rbreak is useful for setting breakpoints on overloaded functions that are not members of any special classes.

Comment: This helped me enormously!
Although I guess it can't be the accepted answer since it matches function names and not the filename of the file it resides in.

Answer (score 8):

**`rbreak foo.cpp:.`**

Here `.` matches anything, and so breaks on all functions of file `foo.cpp`.

Answer (score 2):

Employed Russian's answer looks very good, but since you say:

> I do not know exactly what functions
>   are been called and what functions are
>   not.

Would a report of which functions are hit, generated by a code coverage tool such as [gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) or something involving [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) be a good solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use command:

```
break foo.cpp:function-name
```

Comment: This will only break on one function, but the question is for all functions.

Comment: `rbreak foo.cpp:.` will break on all functions from `foo.cpp` that match regex `.` (that is, all functions from `foo.cpp`).

Answer (score 0):

gdb breakpoints have a couple of syntax... [See here.](http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/localfiles/infofiles/gdb/gdb_29.html#SEC29)

It won't break on any function in the file though....

Edit: You could do something stupid like making all function call a dummy function void foo(void), and breakpoint inside. At least you would break inside the file, and should be trivial to find which function in side of file X is being called.

Comment: It is not a bad idea the foo function, the thing is that I have many methods and files, the only option that maybe I can use is rbreak regex. Thanks