# gdb, set breakpoint on all functions in a file

Tags: function, gdb, breakpoints

Is there a single command in gdb which can set breakpoints on all the functions in a given file ?
I know about rbreak regex which sets breakpoints in matching regular expression functions, but my file doesnt have fixed patterned functions.

In another way, is there a command by which I can set a breakpoint on a filename. Which will mean, whenever control gets inside this file, it should break ?

I personally think this should not be much difficult to implement in gdb, but just wondering if somebody has already done this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using gdb stop the program when it is using any function from file X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475283/using-gdb-stop-the-program-when-it-is-using-any-function-from-file-x)

Answer (score 50):

```
(gdb) rbreak file:.
```

from http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#Set-Breaks

Comment: That doesn't work, and isn't expected to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096624/putting-breakpoint-in-a-file-using-rbreak-filename-c-doesnt-work

Comment: Look for "rbreak file:regex" on the page I linked.  I confirmed that it works in my own examples.

Answer (score 10):

```
(gdb) set height 0
(gdb) rbreak file.cpp:.*
```

worked fine for me.

In my case it was useful to shrink the result set a little bit by specifying a template argument for the functions contained in the file:

```
(gdb) rbreak file.cpp:.*TemplateClass.*
```