# Stop execution (breakpoint) every time the execution enter in one of my classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there any way to stop the execution EVERY time the app enter in one of my classes?

The equivalent would be to put a breakpoint in every single entry point of my class (for ex. viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear...) Sometimes I just need to capture every time my class is called, and I dont know which one is the entry point, so I was obliged to put a breakpoint in every entry point.

Is there any way to automatize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about a class but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476002/gdb-set-breakpoint-on-all-functions-in-a-file) can help you.
Setting the breakpoint on a file.

Comment: Thanks, but is not exactly what I was looking for

Comment: What is the problem with this solution?