# apply breakpoint at the start of each function

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Is there any command in `gdb` by which one can apply breakpoint at the start of each function in a `.C` file.

I need this as i have a very big `C` file which i need to debug and it contains more than 100 functions and i need to find all the functions called during run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rbreak file:regex
```

If you look at this page : http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#Set-Breaks

Look also at the past thread : [gdb, set breakpoint on all functions in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476002/gdb-set-breakpoint-on-all-functions-in-a-file)

Comment: `rbreak file:regex` did not work but I got my answer from the link you shared. Thanks !!

Comment: yes, but logically a regex containing only . match all any character :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use the debugger that way for solving your search.

I would add at the beginning of each function a single assignment and one struct at the file start.

```
struct {
   int foo;
   int bar;
   ...
   int lastFunctionName;
} sFunc;

void foo()
{
  sFunc.foo=1;
  ...
}

void bar()
{
  sFunc.bar=1;
  ...
}
```

Then you can run your program and it collects the informations for you.

Comment: actually initially I thought of adding `printf` at the start of each function but as I set there are hundred of functions in that particular file so it was really a cumbersome job :) +1 for your suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_29.html) states that there is an option `rbreak regexp` which lets you set a regexp to break on all functions matching that regexp. Given that you are in one file (one module?) maybe all the functions are prefixed in the same way?