# putting breakpoint in a file using "rbreak filename.c:." doesn't work

Tags: gdb

I want to put breakpoint on all functions of a file. I came across this link : http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#Set-Breaks

It suggest the use of rbreak command for this purpose. When i use "rbreak ." , it works fine as expected and puts breakpoint in all functions of a prog. But when is use

rbreak filename.c:.

This doesn't work at all and no breakpoint is put anywhere. I even tried a variation of this putting spaces around :, but even that doesn't work.

Any idea on how this can be done ? Is it possible at all ? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
vikas

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using gdb stop the program when it is using any function from file X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475283/using-gdb-stop-the-program-when-it-is-using-any-function-from-file-x)

Comment: make sure your `gdb` version is up-to-date. The `rbreak filename.c:.` command works for me in *gdb 7.6*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> rbreak filename.c:.

That isn't supposed to work. From the document you linked to:

```
rbreak regex
Set breakpoints on all *functions* matching the regular expression regex.
```

This is different from *locations*, where `filename.c:...` is intended to be used.

> I want to put breakpoint on all functions of a file.

This is an unusual request. In my many years of debugging, I've never needed to do that.

You'll have to prepare a list, and set the breakpoints individually. A recipe for doing this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475283/using-gdb-stop-the-program-when-it-is-using-any-function-from-file-x).

Comment: `rbreak filename.c:.` works for me on a recent *gdb 7.6*. It doesn't work in *gdb 7.2*. Your linked recipe works as well. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - just to note the "unusual request"; maybe want OP wants is the call graph during execution, which (I guess) would better be served with tracepoints (which, however, require `gdbserver`); however I myself often forget the 'tracepoints' name, and then I start looking for "set breakpoint at every function", and end up at pages like this `:)` Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

`rbreak filename.cpp:.*` works fine for me.

Note that in order to put breakpoint in a file you need to compile the program with debug info, e.g

```
g++ -g filename.cpp
```