# Gdb conditional regex break

Tags: c, regex, debugging, gdb

Does gdb allow conditional regex breaks?

I have a source file `timer.c`, an `int64_t` ticks, and a function `timer_ticks()` which returns it.
Neither

```
rbreak timer.c:. if ticks >= 24
```

nor

```
rbreak timer.c:. if ticks_ticks() >= 24
```

place any breakpoints.

If I remove however either the regex part or the conditional part, the breakpoints are set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to get it done. It takes a couple of steps, and requires some visual inspection of `gdb`'s output.

First, run the `rbreak` command and note the breakpoint numbers it sets.

```
(gdb) rbreak f.c:.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80486a7: file f.c, line 41.
int f();
Breakpoint 2 at 0x80486ac: file f.c, line 42.
int g();
Breakpoint 3 at 0x80486b1: file f.c, line 43.
int h();
Breakpoint 4 at 0x8048569: file f.c, line 8.
int main(int, char **);
```

Now, loop through that range of breakpoints and use the `cond` command to add the condition to each:

```
(gdb) set $i = 1
(gdb) while ($i <= 4)
 >cond $i ticks >= 24
 >set $i = $i + 1
 >end
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x080486a7 in f at f.c:41
        stop only if ticks >= 24
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x080486ac in g at f.c:42
        stop only if ticks >= 24
3       breakpoint     keep y   0x080486b1 in h at f.c:43
        stop only if ticks >= 24
4       breakpoint     keep y   0x08048569 in main at f.c:8
        stop only if ticks >= 24
```

Comment: Note for future me, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400844/how-do-i-set-the-stack-pointer-from-gdb-using-jlink-and-a-cortex-m4/35663966#comment54623762_33400844), ada mode requires assignment to be `:=`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, it doesn't.

However, there is workaround.

You want to break every function from the file conditionally, don't you?

If yes, you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477988/934691) as start point and then create conditional breaks.

So, first step: get a list of functions in the file:

```
nm a.out | grep ' T ' | addr2line  -fe a.out |
   grep -B1 'foo\.cpp' | grep -v 'foo\.cpp' > funclist
```

Next: create a gdb script that creates breaks:

```
sed 's/^/break /' funclist | sed 's/$/ if ticks>=24/' > stop-in-foo.gdb
```

And finally, import script in gdb:

```
(gdb): source stop-in-foo.gdb
```