# How do I set the stack pointer from gdb using JLink and a Cortex M4?

Tags: gdb, arm, embedded

I am using a Segger J-Link Base with gdb on Linux to debug an Atmel SAM4S8C MCU.  I have the following in a gdb command file that I specify with the `--command` argument when starting gdb:

```
target remote localhost:2331
monitor flash device SAM4S8C
```

I also specify my ELF file and `load` the program in the command file.

I have noticed that when I load my program (using `load`) the stack pointer is not getting set correctly.  `monitor reset` also does not modify the stack pointer.

The [J-Link User Guide](https://www.segger.com/cms/admin/uploads/productDocs/UM08001_JLink.pdf) says (for Cortex-M3 devices):

> Moreover, the user have to correct the Stack pointer (R13) and the PC (R15) manually, after reset in order to debug the application.

What is the command to do this from gdb?

It's strange that I should have to do this manually.  The stack pointer is the first entry of the reset vector.  As I develop my code, the initial stack pointer changes (particularly switching between applications that have very different initial stack pointers, which is how I first noticed this).

Is there a way to get gdb to read this from the ELF file during `load` and automatically set it?

Comment: In context, that statement seems to be specifically about debugging Cortex-M3-based NXP LPC devices out of reset, and appears to be about bypassing their fancy ROM bootloader. As such it doesn't necessarily apply directly to an Atmel device, although the situation may be broadly similar.

Comment: You can set the stack pointer via `set $sp = <value>`, but the details of GDB and flash loading are lost to me, sorry.  All my efforts have been an internally developed ROM and bootloader using commercial tools.

Comment: @RussSchultz Thanks, I was missing the `=` when I tried setting it directly.  Note that when in Ada mode, the stack pointer is set via `set $sp := <value>`.  If using `set $sp = <value>` in Ada mode, gdb will generate the following message:  `warning: Expression is not an assignment (and might have no effect)`.

Answer (score 5):

Cortex-M were designed so that no assembly startup code would be required:
At startup, Cortex-M will automaticaly load sp and pc registers from the two first 32-bits words of flash.
In the case of my LPC1788, that means I need to load r13/sp with the content of *0x00000000*, and r15/pc with the content of *0x00000004*:

```
target remote localhost:2331
monitor interface SWD
monitor endian little
monitor speed auto
monitor reset
monitor halt
monitor flash device = LPC1788
monitor flash download = 1
monitor flash breakpoints = 1
file program.elf
load program.elf
break main
monitor reg r13 = (0x00000000)
monitor reg r15 = (0x00000004) 
continue
```

Comment: The `monitor reg` commands work (thank you!), however I replaced `r13` with `sp` and `r15` with `pc`, and the addresses are `0x00400000` and `0x00400004`, respectively.  If I put this in my startup file, it only works when starting gdb -- it does not work on subsequent `load`s from within the gdb console.  Is there a way to set the registers every time you `load`?

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue as my product used a bootloader located at the start of flash which I wanted to skip while debugging. Since the stack pointer value should be stored as the first word in your executable and the reset vector as the next, you need something like:

```
$sp = {int} program_start_address
$pc = {int} program_start_address + 4
```

e.g. for a binary that starts at 0x08001000

```
$sp = {int} 0x08001000
$pc = {int} 0x08001004
```