# Tools to get a pictorial function call graph of code

Tags: c, function, call-graph

I have a large work space which has many source files of C code. Although I can see the functions called from a function in MS VS2005 using the Object browser, and in MSVC 6.0 also, this only shows functions called from a particular function in a non-graphical kind of display. Additionally, it does not show the function called starting from say `main()`, and then the functions called from it, and so on, deeper inside to the leaf level function.

I need a tool which will give me a function call graph pictorially with functions `callee` and `caller` connected by arrows or something like that, starting from `main()` to the last level of function, or at least showing a call graph of all functions in one C source file pictorially. It would be great if I could print this graph.

Any good tools to do that (need not be free tools)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17844310/1959808

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph#Software

Comment: Related: *[How to generate a call graph for C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373714)*

Answer (score 69, accepted):

- [Egypt](http://www.gson.org/egypt/) (free software)
- [ncc](http://students.ceid.upatras.gr/~sxanth/ncc/)
- [KcacheGrind](https://kcachegrind.github.io/html/Home.html) (GPL)
- [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) (CPL)
- [CodeViz](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~mel/projects/codeviz/) (GPL)

Comment: qusetion about CodeViz,If you pass your code to that it will generate the code or not?Or you should yourself make graph by codevis?

Comment: I just tried Egypt. It graphic is horrible. I am not sure about the others.

Answer (score 34):

**Dynamic analysis methods**

Here I describe a few dynamic analysis methods.

Dynamic methods actually run the program to determine the call graph.

The opposite of dynamic methods are static methods, which try to determine it from the source alone without running the program.

Advantages of dynamic methods:

- catches function pointers and virtual C++ calls. These are present in large numbers in any non-trivial software.

Disadvantages of dynamic methods:

- you have to run the program, which might be slow, or require a setup that you don't have, e.g. cross-compilation
- only functions that were actually called will show. E.g., some functions could be called or not depending on the command line arguments.

**KcacheGrind**

https://kcachegrind.github.io/html/Home.html

Test program:

```
int f2(int i) { return i + 2; }
int f1(int i) { return f2(2) + i + 1; }
int f0(int i) { return f1(1) + f2(2); }
int pointed(int i) { return i; }
int not_called(int i) { return 0; }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int (*f)(int);
    f0(1);
    f1(1);
    f = pointed;
    if (argc == 1)
        f(1);
    if (argc == 2)
        not_called(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
sudo apt-get install -y kcachegrind valgrind

# Compile the program as usual, no special flags.
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -o main -std=c99 main.c

# Generate a callgrind.out.<PID> file.
valgrind --tool=callgrind ./main

# Open a GUI tool to visualize callgrind data.
kcachegrind callgrind.out.1234
```

You are now left inside an awesome GUI program that contains a lot of interesting performance data.

On the bottom right, select the "Call graph" tab. This shows an interactive call graph that correlates to performance metrics in other windows as you click the functions.

To export the graph, right click it and select "Export Graph". The exported PNG looks like this:

[image]

From that we can see that:

- the root node is `_start`, which is the actual ELF entry point, and contains glibc initialization boilerplate
- `f0`, `f1` and `f2` are called as expected from one another
- `pointed` is also shown, even though we called it with a function pointer. It might not have been called if we had passed a command line argument.
- `not_called` is not shown because it didn't get called in the run, because we didn't pass an extra command line argument.

The cool thing about `valgrind` is that it does not require any special compilation options.

Therefore, you could use it even if you don't have the source code, only the executable.

`valgrind` manages to do that by running your code through a lightweight "virtual machine". This also makes execution extremely slow compared to native execution.

As can be seen on the graph, timing information about each function call is also obtained, and this can be used to profile the program, which is likely the original use case of this setup, not just to see call graphs: [How can I profile C++ code running on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/how-can-i-profile-c-code-running-on-linux/60265409#60265409)

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

**`gcc -finstrument-functions` + etrace**

https://github.com/elcritch/etrace

`-finstrument-functions` [adds callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176284/why-doesnt-finstrument-functions-work-for-me), etrace parses the ELF file and implements all callbacks.

I couldn't get it working however unfortunately: [Why doesn't `-finstrument-functions` work for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176284/why-doesnt-finstrument-functions-work-for-me)

Claimed output is of format:

```
\-- main
|   \-- Crumble_make_apple_crumble
|   |   \-- Crumble_buy_stuff
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   \-- Crumble_prepare_apples
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_skin_and_dice
|   |   \-- Crumble_mix
|   |   \-- Crumble_finalize
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_put
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_put
|   |   \-- Crumble_cook
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_put
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_bake
```

Likely the most efficient method besides specific hardware tracing support, but has the downside that you have to recompile the code.

Comment: Just note that the dynamic call graph only covers one run of the program.

Comment: @smwikipedia yes, I've upgraded the answer to make that clearer

Comment: Also explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311840/tool-to-trace-local-function-calls-in-linux

Answer (score 18):

[Understand](http://www.scitools.com/products/understand/) does a very good job of creating call graphs.

Answer (score 12):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) has [static control/dataflow/points-to/call graph analysis](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/FlowAnalysis.html) that has been applied to huge systems (~~25 million lines) of C code, and produced such call graphs, *including functions called via function pointers*.

Comment: Ah, nice, its 2016 and now a downvoter shows up.   I'm sure his downvote was based on an accurate assessment that this tool cannot do this.  Well, maybe not.  It sure does what OP requested.

Comment: Take an upvote to counter that. I don't care it it's your software or proprietary as long as it gets the job done :-)

Answer (score 11):

You may try CScope + [tceetree](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tceetree/) + [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Comment: How to use this combination to get the graph, is there a tutorial or at least some explanation.

Comment: @Muhammad Yusuf yes, there is a [wiki page](https://sourceforge.net/p/tceetree/wiki/Home/).

Comment: For people that find this through google, this toolchain works for other languages too, including processing and java, though it doesn't seem to like java's object initialization, and doesn't recognize new as containing a function call.

Answer (score 6):

You can check out my bash-based C call tree generator [here](http://toolchainguru.blogspot.com/2011/03/c-calltrees-in-bash-revisited.html). It lets you specify one or more C functions for which you want caller and/or called information, or you can specify a set of functions and determine the reachability graph of function calls that connects them... I.e. tell me all the ways main(), foo(), and bar() are connected. It uses graphviz/dot for a graphing engine.

Answer (score 5):

[Astrée](http://www.absint.com/astree/) is the most robust and sophisticated tool out there, IMHO.