# Tool to generate call graphs for C/C++ code on the Windows platform

Tags: c++, c, windows, call-graph

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Tools to get a pictorial function call graph of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517589/tools-to-get-a-pictorial-function-call-graph-of-code)

I have some C/C++ code. Is there a tool that can be used to generate call graphs, giving information regarding caller, etc. on the Windows platform?

Answer (score 4):

Doxygen can create call graphs
http://www.doxygen.nl//manual/diagrams.html

Comment: Remember to install [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) as well.

Comment: @IraBaxter, it talks about both.  From the page "if CALL_GRAPH is set to YES, a graphical call graph is drawn"

Answer (score 1):

You can try also [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com). It comes with a dependency graph with many features and possibilities, and you can use CQLinq to request your codebase and see the dependency graph for a subset of your codebase.