# Function mapping diagram

Tags: c++, class, diagrams

Hi this question is very broad.

SCENARIO --
I want to diagrammatically represent the functions of my class and how they call each other? The functions have a definite pattern and I want to do this to accommodate future changes such as adding a new functionality which will require to write a new function.

Eg:

function_1() ---> calls function_master()

function_2() ---> calls function_master()

If tomorrow function_3 is created then the makers should know that they need to make a call to  function_master().

There are many such complex relationships.

The Real Question --> What I'm trying to achieve, does it have a name? like function mapping diagram. 
I know about class diagrams. I don't want to include them. I want detailed diagram of only functions calling each other.

Can you suggest some tools so that I can make it?

Comment: Duplicate of [Tools to get a pictorial function call graph of code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517589/tools-to-get-a-pictorial-function-call-graph-of-code) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a **function call graph**.
A tool that may be used is [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)

Answer (score 0):

[Imagix 4D](http://www.imagix.com/products/source-code-analysis.html) will be of great help to you.

You may also look at [wiki's link for static Analysis tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis)