# generate dynamic call graph gcov or gprof?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, instrumentation, gprof

I am interested in finding out the exact functions that were executed from the main() until the program terminated in the same order they were called and also identify the lines in those functions that were executed in the same order in which they were executed..

so much like a path, from a start node (main function) to an end node (program termination). Is this something that is possible in gcop or gprof?

Thanks

Comment: probably [Backtraces](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) or [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/)

Comment: Does this SO thread provide anything useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517589/tools-to-get-a-pictorial-function-call-graph-of-code

Comment: valgrind's callgrind module may help.

Comment: Hey, I am actually looking for like a textfile or if possible xml to be generated since I want to process this information

Comment: @user3259045 yes but that's the easy part. Hard part is finding a tool that does what you need regardless of the format it outputs.