# What's the easiest way to write an instrumenting profiler for C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, profiling

I've seen a few tools like [Pin](http://www.pintool.org) and [DynInst](http://www.dyninst.org/) that do dynamic code manipulation in order to instrument code without having to recompile. These seem like heavyweight solutions to what seems like it should be a straightforward problem: retrieving accurate function call data from a program.

I want to write something such that in my code, I can write

```
void SomeFunction() {
  StartProfiler();
  ...
  StopProfiler();
}
```

and post-execution, retrieve data about what functions were called between `StartProfiler()` and `StopProfiler()` (the whole call tree) and how long each of them took.

Preferably I could read out debug symbols too, to get function names instead of addresses.

Comment: If you can use Linux, try callgrind (from valgrind) to get call tree. It will dynamically translate and instrument your program and show all function calls in tree format (+check kcachgrind GUI). There are also some system-wide profilers capable of drawing call-trees (like linux pref or google-perftools), but their callgraph is taken only at some sampling interval (e.g. every 1 ms) and is inaccurate.

Comment: I'm on OS X, but I think (parts of) valgrind have been ported there recently?

Comment: valgrind is OSX 10.6/10.7 only; 10.8 support is limited. Also, callgrind has no "START"/"STOP" macro (only `--instr-atstart=no` and callgrind_control utility) , and it will draw summary a tree without dumping full calltrace (but internally it has one). Also, check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311840/tool-to-trace-local-function-calls-in-linux if you want to get trace of all calls (most answers needs only scripting and gdb). I usually use this solution: http://blog.superadditive.com/2007/12/01/call-graphs-using-the-gnu-project-debugger/

Answer (score 3):

Here's one interesting hint at a solution I discovered.

gcc (and llvm>=3.0) has a `-pg` option when compiling, which is traditionally for gprof support. When you compile your code with this flag, the compiler adds a call to the function `mcount` to the beginning of every function definition. You can override this function, but you'll need to do it in assembly, otherwise the `mcount` function you define will be instrumented with a call to `mcount` and you'll quickly run out of stack space before `main` even gets called.

Here's a little proof of concept:

foo.c:

```
int total_calls = 0;
void foo(int c) {
  if (c > 0)
    foo(c-1);
}
int main() {
  foo(4);
  printf("%d\n", total_calls);
}
```

foo.s:

```
.globl mcount
mcount:
  movl  _total_calls(%rip), %eax
  addl  $1, %eax
  movl  %eax, _total_calls(%rip)
  ret
```

compile with `clang -pg foo.s foo.c -o foo`. Result:

```
$ ./foo
6
```

That's 1 for `main`, 4 for `foo` and 1 for `printf`.

Here's the asm that clang emits for `foo`:

```
_foo:
  pushq %rbp
  movq  %rsp, %rbp
  subq  $16, %rsp
  movl  %edi, -8(%rbp)          ## 4-byte Spill
  callq mcount
  movl  -8(%rbp), %edi          ## 4-byte Reload
  ...
```

Comment: why do it in assembly, when we can write it in C and put to separate source file which is to be compiled without -pg.

Comment: That's a good idea :) Another possibility would be to write it in C and write a small assembly shim which would jump into the function after the generated `callq mcount`.