# tracing program function calls

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, trace

I played a bit with `strace` and `ltrace` These are wonderful tools. Is there any tool that does the same with the functions of my applications?

I am aware of `system tap` and `ftrace` but these require the debug version of the kernel that is something I cant' install at the moment. I don't need kernel or system calls tracing.

I really need something like `strace` able to discriminate also across thread and display functions per threads.

Do I really have to implement that by using -finstrument-functions and provide a printf of the function that is called?

```
 THREAD ID A  function #1
 THREAD ID B  function #2
 THREAD ID A  function #3
 THREAD ID A  function #4
 THREAD ID C  function #5
```

I read this post as reference

[Tool to trace local function calls in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311840/tool-to-trace-local-function-calls-in-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, profiling is the only way to do this.

All you will get is the function address, which you can map again to its name by dladdr() API.

All the best!!!!